# wso2 esb not running on linux server

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I have some problem with my wso2-esb, it is on a remote linux server and seems to be succesfully started:
[image]

But when I try to access it, does not work:

[image]

I am not any expert in servers, it is the first time I do such thing, so I probably missed some basic step or something you might know.
Please suggest

Thanks a lot

**SOLVED** the server was firewalled, I had to add an exception to access it

Comment: Did you notice that you are accessing the management console 192.168.1.182 but in your case, it should be 192.168.10.182. I think the issue is a simple matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things might be happening.

1. IE is masking an HTTP error response with its friendly errors.
2. Since this is a remote server, iptables could be running on the server, or there is another firewall in the way blocking that port.

To diagnose, I would start by disabling friendly error messages in IE, or using a different browser that doesn't do this. Instructions on how to disable it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778248(v=ws.10).aspx

Next, if that doesn't resolve it, I would try running curl/wget on the server, and requesting the displayed URL. curl can be run with `curl example.com` and wget `wget -qO- example.com`, both will displayed the returned data (if any) on the terminal. If one returns a command not found, try the other. If that doesn't work, something is going on with your server. If it's returning something that looks like an error (e.g. a sever generated error page), I'd look into that too at this step.

If you appear to have connectivity issues, you can see if there's any iptables rules in place by running `iptables -L` on the server. A `DROP all` under `Chain INPUT` would cause this. You can read more about iptables here, and how to set it up for your needs here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo (Even if you're not using ubuntu, this will still work for you, look in the "Allowing Incoming Traffic on Specific Ports" section, there's an example there you would need to adopt slightly for the non-standard port the server is running on). If there's an external firewall preventing access, you would need to talk with whoever is managing the sever.

Comment: At the end it was a problem with Browser's proxy settings, but I will accept your answer because it was really detailed and helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its seems some network issue. Can you try to ping the IP. If you cannt ping that means the machine is not reachable.

Regards,
/nuwan